# extracting data from dicts that have different key value names but are in same format (matlab to python)

Tags: python, matlab, dictionary

I will give some background, I am importing matlab files into colab notebook, each of the matlab files has a different name. Im am using the following

```
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('/content/B_21_3HP_12K_DE.mat')
```

which returns a dict with these keys

```
dict_keys(['__header__', '__version__', '__globals__', 'X225_DE_time'])
```

I am trying to get the values from 'X225_DE_time' into an array

I have a number of these files to do and each time the key I need is slightly different, it could  be 'X32_FE_TIME'

I want to loop through the files in a directory and put the values from the key I require into the array, if this was a list I would  use index  but dicts are not 'easily' supported this way?

What is the correct way to do this with dicts then? I did try convert to df but the issue persist if the key has a different name each time.

Comment: So do all the desired keys end with `_time` or `_TIME`? If so, something like `keys = [key for key in mat if '_time' in key.lower()]` would work.

Comment: Alternatively, if you only have the four keys and the first three are the same `valid_key = [key for key in mat if key not in ['__header__','__version__','__globals__']][0]`

Comment: @Ftagliacarne If you're going to assume that, just use `[keys[-1] for keys in mat]`.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal Not really, because you don't know (maybe) if they are in that order, I meant the first three as in the example. Also it would be `list(mat.keys())[-1]` as the other one does not work. But in the end we are making assumptions based on the little info we have...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def process(name):
  mat = scipy.io.loadmat(name)

  if time in key.lower():
      key = key for key in mat

  if key == key:
      values = [value for key, value in mat.items()] 

  final_data = np.array(second_values)
  final_data = final_data[3]
  return(final_data)
```

Comment: Please explain how the code you posted is an answer, and how it’s different from the other answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer —— What is the value of variable `time`? And `key` in the first `if` statement where it hasn’t been defined yet? Doesn’t `key for key in mat` require brackets around it? What is `if key == key`? Isn’t that always true?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips, works well with the following function, however it needs further processing to get the data I required.

```
def process_data(file_name):
  mat = scipy.io.loadmat(file_name)
  key = [key for key in mat if '_time' in key.lower()]
  values = [value for key, value in mat.items() if key == key]
  data_array = np.array(values2)
  data_array = data_array[3]
  return(data_array)
```

Comment: Please explain the code you posted a bit, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer —— why `if key == key`? I’m guessing the second `key` is defined in the previous line and Python somehow allows two variables with the same name in that context? But isn’t the `key` from the previous line a list? And why do you then need to get the 4th element from the list? ( `data_array = data_array[3]`) Maybe that whole key selection thing is not working at all because `key == key` is always true, and you just pick the 4th element from the dictionary?